# The default style for changing render events in fullcalendar inset:44px 0% -132px

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

Where do I start if I want to change the code for rendering events provided by default in fullcalendar? I just want to change the default introvert style that fullcalendar provides when rendering events, inset:44px 0%-132px;

[image]

I tried to harness a style in one of its classes:.fc-timegrid-event-harness and use it! import to override the introverted style, but only render the last event in the day's events. I then tried to add a body weight to the class to override the style style, but still failed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can write your own CSS rule to override it